# Convert string containing date time and timezone to UTC datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a string in the following format 
"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm zzz" for example 14-Sep-2019 13:05 EST"
timezone can be any existing timezone. I need to convert it to DateTime and UTC.

I know how to convert timezone abbreviations to time offset I have a dictionary for that. So I can transfer change the string to 14-Sep-2019 13:05 -005 for instance. What is the best way to convert it to date time UTC ?

Comment: format for 14-Sep-2019 will be dd-MMM-yyyy, not the one you mentioned. MM for 09, MMM for Sep and MMMM for September

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date time string have 13:05 showing 24hours based time so HH would be used for hour instead of hh and -5:00 in date time string representing EST time zone

```
string dateTimeString = "14-Sep-2019 13:05 -5:00";

//local date time as per given time zone in date time string
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dateTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTime, "UTC");
```

Comment: You can also use `dateTime.ToUniversalTime()`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is your friend, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones)

```
var date = "14-SEP-2019 13:05 -05:00";
var format = "dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm zzz";
var dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime());
```